# can you add an extra parameter to DateAdd function?

Tags: sql, ms-access

i'm using dateadd to sum 2 fields in my access query, but i want to always add "1" year to the result of the dateadd.

Example:

`Dateadd('yyyy', [field1],[field2]) + 1`

it's not working. It's only giving me the sum of `Dateadd('yyyy', [field1],[field2])`

Field1 = date
Field2 = number

example:

field1 = 2020-01-01

field2 = 2

i want 2020-01-01 + 2 + 1(I always want to add 1 year at the end)

I should get 2023-01-01

Comment: That's not how DateAdd is supposed to work. DateAdd doesn't just sum two values. Also, adding 1 to a date just adds 1 day because day is default unit for arithmetic with date value. Edit question to show sample data from the fields. Possibly you want: `DateAdd("yyyy", 1, [field1] + [field2])`. And no, can't add parameters to intrinsic functions.

Comment: Please illustrate your needs with data.

Comment: @June7 it's not working. I'm using dateadd because field1 is a date, field2 is a number.

Comment: @Parfait I modified my question to explain a bit more. Thank you

Comment: it's actually working, but the '1' is adding 1 day and not 1 year @June7

Comment: Really just need to add 1 to whatever is in field1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
DATEADD(‘yyyy’, ([field2]+1), [field1])
```

Comment: it's not working. it's not adding the '1' at the end!..

Comment: it's actually working, but the '1' is adding 1 day and not 1 year

Comment: @Stuart has it almost correct. Add 1 to field1.

Comment: i just did +365 lol, thanks all

Comment: Not every year has 365 days but maybe that's close enough.

Comment: Sorry, was answering from my phone; that’s correct, it should be flipped. :)

Answer (score 0):

If its giving you that much difficulty, call it twice via

```
Dateadd('yyyy', 1, Dateadd('yyyy', [field1],[field2]))
```

So the inner is processed first giving you whatever date + years to add.  From that, the OUTER DateAdd will just add 1 year to the inner result.

But I suspect it is because your context of field is incorrect.  The second parameter is how many years, days, months, whatever you want to advance.  The THIRD is the date.  So by you having a bad naming sample of field1, field2 instead of MyDateField, MyYearsToAddField, it would make more sense now and the future.  So it SHOULD PROBABLY work as

```
Dateadd('yyyy', 1 + MyYearsToAddField, MyDateField )
```

Comment: @June7, yup, I was rewriting due to apparent incorrect parameter sequencing and bad names for variable context.